# Python run code every 100th loop item

Tags: python

I have this simple loop in Python that I am using..

```
for i, numbercode in enumerate(numbercode_list):
    print ("Item : %s" %i )
    driver.close()
    driver = init_driver()
```

How would I go about just running the last two lines every 100th loop item?  Currently it runs them every time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can take the modulus of the number and compare to zero. Modulo (`%` in Python) yields [the remainder from the division of the first argument by the second](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations), e.g.

```
>>> 101 % 100
1

>>> 100 % 100
0
```

For your example, this could be applied as follows:

```
for i, numbercode in enumerate(numbercode_list):
    print ("Item : %s" %i )
    if i % 100 == 0:
        driver.close()
        driver = init_driver()
```

Comment: If you don't want the code to run on the first loop (`i=0`), then change to `(i + 1) % 100 == 0`.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the modulo operation?

```
for i in range(1000):
    if i%100==0:
        print i
```

Edit: Sorry, too slow

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something more Pythonic:

```
for i in range(1000)[::100]:
    if i%100==0:
        print i
```

The `[::100]` takes every 100-th item of your list. So this assumes `numbercode_list` is a list or array.

Comment: Won't allow him to execute first line during each loop cycle.